# Postfix 'tlsv1 alert unknown ca'

Tags: ssl, postfix, dovecot

I have VPS (server A) and hosting (server B). On the **server A**, I've set up mail server (debian, postfix, dovecot, postfixadmin and roundcube, self-signed cert, TLS only auth) which works fine:

- I can send and recieve messages logged via roundcube,
- I can send and recieve messages from post client (eg thunderbird),
- I can send emails from website on my local machine,
- I can send emails from website hosted on **server B** (symfony2/swiftmailer).

Problem is that it's impossilble to send emails from website (exact copy of original website from **server B**) hosted on **server A** (same as mail server). I get following messages in log:

> Oct 26 19:45:00 vps105120 postfix/smtpd[3107]: connect from *domain*[*ip*]
>   Oct 26 19:45:00 vps105120 postfix/smtpd[3107]: SSL_accept error from *domain*[*ip*]: 0
>   Oct 26 19:45:00 vps105120 postfix/smtpd[3107]: warning: TLS library problem: 3107:error:14094418:SSL rutines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:s3_pkt.c:1258:SSL alert number 48:
>   Oct 26 19:45:00 vps105120 postfix/smtpd[3107]: lost connection after STARTTLS from *domain*[*ip*]
>   Oct 26 19:45:00 vps105120 postfix/smtpd[3107]: disconnect from *domain*[*ip*]

Any ideas what to do with this?

Comment: Apparently your server B is configured to only set up encrypted connections to servers providing a certificate with a CA in your trust chain. So either add an exception, import the CA or configure your setup in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out :), as expected turned out to be as simple as possible...

My cert wasn't readable by openssl, after adding link named as cert hash to /etc/ssl/certs/ everything works like a charm.

Comment: Could you please elaborate you answer. I am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen with Let's encrypt certificate. I had similar problem which was caused by using cert.pem in postfix configuration. I resolved it by changing certificate to fullchain.pem. Most smtp clients were OK. Problem was mostly with php clients.