# Postfix TLS Error

Tags: postfix, email-server, tls, roundcube

I'm working with a Postfix/Dovecot/Roundcube setup, aiming for a virtual user mail system that can send mail through the internet, as documented [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Virtual_user_mail_system).

Everything seems to work well; Dovecote shows no problems, I can telnet into all of my ports; however, whenever I try to send mail through Roundcube I get the error:

```
SMTP Error (220): Authentication failed.
```

And from the logs:

```
[17-Jan-2015 05:27:31 +0000]: SMTP Error: SMTP error: Authentication failure: STARTTLS failed (Code: ) in /usr/share/webapps/roundcubemail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php on line 1505 (POST /roundcube/?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1421472451594&_lang=en_US&_framed=1?_task=mail&_action=send)
```

I figured since Postfix is responsible for SMTP, it must be the culprit. In my Postfix logs I'm seeing:

```
Jan 16 21:14:35 steelhorse postfix/smtpd[18426]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan 16 21:14:35 steelhorse postfix/smtpd[18426]: lost connection after STARTTLS from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan 16 21:14:35 steelhorse postfix/smtpd[18426]: warning: TLS library problem: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:s3_pkt.c:1293:SSL alert number
Jan 16 21:14:35 steelhorse postfix/smtpd[18426]: SSL_accept error from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: 0
```

My SSL certificate is signed with localhost as the CN as that fixed a different issue I was having. Postfix was set with the $myhostname parameter to be mail.[mydomain] and using Afraid DynDNS I set an A record for mail.mydomain as well as an MX record that went like 1:mail.[mydomain]. I tried setting these all to just [mydomain] and it didn't work. A telnet sessions looks like this:

```
telnet [mydomain] 587
Trying [myip]...
Connected to [mydomain].
Escape character is '^]'.
220 [mydomain] ESMTP Postfix
ehlo [mydomain]
250-[mydomain]
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

My Postfix main.cf (Not including most of the default lines):

```
#soft_bounce = no
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/bin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
#default_privs = nobody
myhostname = [mydomain]
#myhostname = virtual.domain.tld
mydomain = [mydomain]
#myorigin = $myhostname
myorigin = $mydomain
#inet_interfaces = all
#inet_interfaces = $myhostname
#inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
#proxy_interfaces =
#proxy_interfaces = 1.2.3.4
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
...
#local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
#mynetworks_style = class
#mynetworks_style = subnet
mynetworks_style = host
#mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
#mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
#mynetworks = hash:/etc/postfix/network_table
#relay_domains = $mydestination
#relayhost = $mydomain
...
relay_domains = *
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_limit = 512000000
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
local_transport = virtual
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,     reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
```

I've also tried setting the Roundcube smtp_conn_options to null as per [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/655995/roundcube-postfix-smtp-ssl-routinesssl3-read-bytestlsv1-alert-unknown-cas3). I'm really not sure if the issues lies in the DNS records, the SSL cert or what. Any and all help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

After setting my Roundcube conf.inc.php to verify_peer(_name) = false

```
/* Local configuration for Roundcube Webmail */
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://roundcube_user:steelcube@localhost/roundcube_db';
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://localhost/';
$config['default_port'] = 993;
$config['smtp_server'] = 'tls://localhost/';
$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
$config['smtp_auth_type'] = 'LOGIN';
$config['smtp_conn_options'] = null;
$config['imap_conn_options'] = array(
  'ssl'         => array(
     'verify_peer'  => false,
     'verfify_peer_name' => false,
   ),
);
$config['smtp_conn_options'] = array(
  'ssl'         => array(
     'verify_peer'      => false,
     'verify_peer_name' => false,
  ),
);

$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
$config['support_url'] = '';
$config['des_key'] = '[secret]';
$config['plugins'] = array('archive', 'zipdownload');
$config['mime_types'] = '/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types';
```

This gives me new the error `SMTP Error (535): Authentication failed` when send email. Here the content of roundcube error

```
[18-Jan-2015 02:58:06 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/webapps/roundcubemail/program/lib/Net/SMTP.php on line 371
[18-Jan-2015 02:58:06 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/share/webapps//roundcubemail/program/lib/Net/SMTP.php on line 371
[18-Jan-2015 02:58:06 +0000]: SMTP Error: SMTP error: Failed to set sender /roundcubemail/program/lib/Net/SMTP.php on line 371'[username]@[mydomain]' in /usr/share/webapps/roundcubemail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php on line 1505 (POST /roundcube/?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1421549886598&_lang=en_US&_framed=1?_task=mail&_action=send)
```

And maillog entry

```
Jan 18 20:18:21 steelhorse postfix/smtpd[1942]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan 18 20:18:21 steelhorse postfix/smtpd[1942]: Anonymous TLS connection established from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128    
Jan 18 20:18:21 steelhorse postfix/smtpd[1942]: warning: localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
Jan 18 20:18:21 steelhorse postfix/smtpd[1942]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
```

As requested in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20348/discussion-between-steelcowboy-and-masegaloeh), this is the output of `dovecot -a | grep auth_mechanism`

```
auth_mechanisms = plain
```

Comment: Looks just like [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/655995/126632). See if the answers help you.

Comment: If the other answer does not help, please post the configs of roundcube and postfix.

Comment: Thanks Michael, saw that and tried the solution with no luck. And masegaloeh, are you saying I should repeat the array I have for IMAP in the SMTP connection options?

Comment: I actually just tried that and now I get: SMTP Error (535): Authentication failed.

Comment: You should set smtp_conn_options not imap_conn_options. Set smtp_conn_options with verify_peer(_name) =  false

Comment: Same result unfortunately. Could it be a Postfix error? There's a lot going on with my domain name and localhost, not sure which Roundcube should be configured to use

Comment: As per an [Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=187063), I set both imap and smtp with verify_peer to false. This returns a new error: SMTP Error (535): Authentication failed.

Comment: Thanks for update config, could you post the relevant /var/log/maillog line too :)?

Comment: Using Arch Linux, doesn't appear that file is used... which program generates that file usually? I can give the journal output

Comment: maillog = Postfix logs [like your question above] :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20348/discussion-between-steelcowboy-and-masegaloeh).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK looks like there are too many mismatch in your postfix, roundcube and dovecot configuration. Let's break it down one by one.

### STARTTLS error

This log line

```
warning: TLS library problem: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:s3_pkt.c:1293:SSL alert number
```

indicated that PHP fails to verify peer certificate because unknown CA. This is exact duplicate problem with this question: [Roundcube & Postfix SMTP: SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:s3_pkt.c](https://serverfault.com/q/655995/218590). And from the question you already solves it by add these lines in roundcube

```
$config['smtp_conn_options'] = array(
  'ssl'         => array(
     'verify_peer'      => false,
     'verify_peer_name' => false,
  ),
);
```

### Authentication failed error

To do this, we must look in postfix and roundcube logs to identify the problem. The real message was captured in postfix log file

```
Jan 18 20:18:21 steelhorse postfix/smtpd[1942]: warning: localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
```

Now because the postfix SASL mechanism  was provided by dovecot then you should check the mechanism that dovecot offer by run `dovecot -a | grep auth_mechanism`.

By looking to roundcube `$config['smtp_auth_type']` and dovecot `auth_mechanisms` config, you can see  a mismatch between these two. Dovecot only offer PLAIN mechanism. But the roundcube was configure to use LOGIN mechanism.

Solution can be one or both of these

- [Offering LOGIN mechanism](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/Mechanisms) from dovecot side by adding

  ```
  auth_mechanisms = plain login
  ```

  in dovecot config.
- [Set PLAIN login to roundcube side](http://trac.roundcube.net/browser/github/config/defaults.inc.php) by change the parameter to

  ```
  $config['smtp_auth_type'] = 'PLAIN';
  ```

Comment: That fixed my problem, I can send myself mails internally! Only thing is Postfix can't send mails to Gmail for example nor receive, though that's probably more a Postfix/MX record/wrong domain issue. But thank you so much for your help, such a sneaky little issue!

Comment: It's potentially insecure to disable 'verify_peer'.

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve this problem, producing a fullchain.
After you have a correct fullchain, add the fullchain to:

```
etc/postfix/main.cf
```

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/some-cert-file-with-fullchain.crt
```

Producing a fullchain can be done by adding the cert **over** an chain-bundle.

No need to change somethgin roundcube config.

The fullchain also will solve login problems in dovecot.